# SVN Include and Ignore another repository

Tags: svn

I have two repos, one has setup and installation scripts which configure all sorts of things within a project.  The second repo is the project itself.

The setup scripts need to be housed inside the project but I don't want them committed to the project.

I normally ignore the setup scripts via svn-ignore and then manually copy the scripts into the project so that they can be executed.

The trouble with this is that the scripts may change over time and I want to keep them all up-to-date.

I'm looking for a way to checkout the setup scripts into the projects working directory whilst ignoring them at the same time.

This way I keep the setup scripts up-to-date in each project but at the same time not have them included in any export or deployment.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I've tried combining svn externals and svn ignore properties but this hasn't worked.  The solution I came up with was to symbolically link the scripts working directory into a folder in the projects working directory. I then used the svn-ignore property to keep this folder out of the project commits. I can still modify the scripts and commit them back to their own repository. So far this solution is working quite well

Comment: Why are you not wanting them in the same repository? It sounds like they should be - you'd not have to worry about keeping them up to date.

Comment: The two repositories are separated as one holds bash + php  scripts that I wouldn’t want deployed on any production server. One of the scripts configures the local environment by dropping and recreating a database. It also reconfigures the current project working directory by setting svn ignore and external properties. After this it builds a composer schema and populates the vendor directory (Which it has just added). Essentially its a suite of scripts that are used to build and update a local dev environment. Once the project is ready I then use Capistrano to deploy the project.

Comment: I think it may be worth looking into having a single repo and reworking the deploy to lay down only what you want.

Comment: Agreed this is a far better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us an example of the URLs for the scripts and project? It'll help us come up with something.

Off the top of my head, I would say that your whatever build script you're using should take care of copying over the setup scripts (via a `svn export`) to your working directory. What language do you program in?

Also, take a look at my [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook). `svn:ignore` is only for the current directory and is *advisory* in nature. It doesn't prevent someone from committed the files, and if the files are committed, `svn:ignore` does nothing. My pre-commit hook allows you to prevent someone from committing entire directory trees.

Let's say your Subversion repository is laid out this way: `http://svnserver/svn/trunk/myproject`. You build your projects under the `dist` directory directly under project root. Thus, you don't want the user to add a `http://svnserver/svn/trunk/myproject/dist` directory, or any subdirectories under that.

With my pre-commit hook, you could setup your control file to look like this:

```
[file You can't add files into the in the build area of your project.]
file=/*/*/dist/**
access=read-only
users=@ALL
```

Now, a user won't be able to add in a `dist` directory under the `myproject` directory, or any subdirectories or files under that.

If I understand what you want, this should help.

Comment: The repos are structured like `/svnserver/projectN/trunk` `/svnserver/scripts/trunk` Projects share a core code base (another repo) which is managed by svn-externals. This sits in a folder in `projectN/trunk/core`. Each project has its own repo and any code that is specific to the project is added to either src,assets or config folders.In order to create a vanilla dev environment I create a blank repo,add the build scripts and into `projectN/trunk/scripts/install` and run them. I need to keep the install folder hidden from Capistrano but at the same time keep the install folder up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution i altered the paths in the install scripts and added some prompts that ask 
questions such as the locations of the projects.

The database scripts are still held with the projects repo but the scripts that run those are not.

Ive essentially decoupled the install scripts from the projects and i can now run the install outside of the project.

When an install is ran the first thing it does is scan the projects folder and prompts me for a project selection.